# Error after upgrading from DNN 7.0 to 7.4.1 (Version Upgrade package)

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

After completing an upgrade to DNN 7.4 I get the error outlined below. Everything went smoothly and there were no errors in the install log. This happens on any page, and there are no new dependencies on Visual Studio I presume...

```
2015-06-12 17:43:49,567 [scrumorg-stage][Thread:5][ERROR] DotNetNuke.Common.Internal.EventHandlersContainer`1[[DotNetNuke.Services.FileSystem.IFileEventHandlers, DotNetNuke, Version=7.4.1.280, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] - The type initializer for 'DotNetNuke.ExtensionPoints.ExtensionPointManager' threw an exception.
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'DotNetNuke.ExtensionPoints.ExtensionPointManager' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandle(Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.IsCustomAttributeDefined(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Int32 attributeCtorToken, Boolean mustBeInheritable)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.IsDefined(RuntimeType type, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.AttributedModel.AttributedPartCreationInfo.IsPartDiscoverable()
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.AttributedModel.AttributedModelDiscovery.CreatePartDefinitionIfDiscoverable(Type type, ICompositionElement origin)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.TypeCatalog.get_PartsInternal()
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.TypeCatalog.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at DotNetNuke.ExtensionPoints.SafeDirectoryCatalog..ctor(String directory)
   at DotNetNuke.ExtensionPoints.ExtensionPointManager.InitializeMefCompositionContainer()
   at DotNetNuke.ExtensionPoints.ExtensionPointManager..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at DotNetNuke.ExtensionPoints.ExtensionPointManager.ComposeParts(Object[] attributeParts)
   at DotNetNuke.Common.Internal.EventHandlersContainer`1..ctor()
```

Any ideas what I'm missing or what might be happening?

Comment: Did you tried to comment that assembly reference in web.config file?

Comment: try downloading the install package for 7.4.1 and pull just the web.config out of the zip package.  Compare this with your existing web.config using a text comparison tool.  I have seen errors on my upgrades in the past which were because of missing pieces in the web.config.

Comment: Good suggestion! I took the web.config from the install version and did nothing else but update the connection strings and machine keys....still resulted in the error above. Oddly, this error is referring to mstest, I'm wondering if maybe there is a problem with this distro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this issue ended up being a custom DLL found in the BIN folder of the DNN website that Ryan was upgrading.

My non-scientific approach to resolving this was to:

1. Remove DLLS in bulk in the BIN folder (keep a copy of the DLLs as you aren't sure which one is the problem, put them back after testing)
2. Load the site (using admin/site settings page)
3. See if page still errored, if so, repeat steps 1 and 2

Ends up the DLL that was causing the problem was I believe a webservice/api URL for testing. Removing that corrected the issue on the 7.3.4 instance of DNN that they were using.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer Chris!

Comment: Specifically, a unit test made its way into a production assembly and was deployed (along with its reference to MS Test). The error was difficult to trace because the MEF error being thrown is not assembly specific....it was literally any number of assemblies.